# Solidify modifier creates edges with a different thicknesses

Tags: modeling

I create a car model. I wanna make a rooftop of this car for first and I use Solidify modifier for this. After I used this modifier I got edges with different thicknesses. Here is what I mean:[image]
One edge has the thickness 0.023 another - 0.0231. Is there a way to fix this or I don't understand something. Help me, please.

Comment: If 'even thickness' was checked, the segments at angles are the diagonal intersection of the flat parts... so they are a bit longer. If you don't want that uncheck 'even thickness' (but linear part won't be straight in that case).

Comment: I do not understand. Can you explain this in other words?

Comment: Solidify Modifier have an even thickness checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

[image]

The figure on the top here has *"even thickness"* unchecked.

That means the modifier makes so all segments length are the same. But as you can see the flat parts are uneven because the corner has the same length as the extremities.

The figure on the bottom has *"even thickness"* checked.

Here the flat parts are regular. But the segment at the corner does not have the same size compared to the extremities.

Now look at this figure:

[image]

When *"even thickness"* is checked, Blender calculates the intersection of 2 flat parts. Like intersecting 2 rectangles. That means (as shown with the green segment here above) that the length at the corner must be larger than the others.